# How to fix 'Horizontal swiping between ViewPager tabs'?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a `RecyclerView` inside two tabs.

The problem is: When I scroll to the top of the list and then trying to swipe horizontally to the next tab, no horizontal movement happens for a while.
**"That happens only when scrolling to the top or the end of the list"**.

**Hint: I'm using `CollapsingToolbarLayout`**.

I tried to make `setNestedScrollingEnabled()` to be (false).
That fixes the problem of horizontal swiping but will disable collapsing.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Izn55.gif)

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
......>

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/my_coordinator_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:expandedTitleGravity="top"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">


                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:contentDescription="@null"
                        android:src="@drawable/dictionary" />
                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
                app:tabMode="fixed">

                     <! Two tabs here >

            </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        ...../>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    ....../>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Java snippet:

```
    mRecyclerView = mRootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    // For linear displaying.
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mRootView.getContext());
    mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    WordsAdapter mAdapter = new WordsAdapter(mWords, this);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out [detecting gestures](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector#java). Your problem is caused by the RecyclerView intercepting the touch events with slight vertical movement. If you were to move your finger perfectly horizontal, you could switch between tabs, but a normal swiping motion has some vertical component. To solve your problem, you could add an onTouchListener to your RecyclerView where you only intercept touch events which are mostly vertical. That way the horizontal swipes will be delivered to the TabView below.

Comment: Glad I could help. If my answer was helpful to you, I'd appreciate if you marked it as accepted.

Comment: Yea of course I will mark it don't worry :), I just waiting for finish solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This problem solved by just adding: **`viewPager.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);`**

Java snippet:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    viewPager.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```